# Right align ComboBox suggestion list when AutoComplete is enabled in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete

I'm working on a program and need all text to be right aligned. Everything works except for that `DropDownList` of suggestions I get when I use the `ComboBox` - `AutoComplete`.

I've searched for an answer here already and couldn't find any.

Does anyone know of a way to change the alignment there?

Edit:
my combo box is defined like this:

```
this.comboBox2.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
this.comboBox2.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
resources.ApplyResources(this.comboBox2, "comboBox2");
this.comboBox2.Name="comboBox2";
this.comboBox2.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
```

Comment: If you set `RightToLeft` property of `ComboBox` to `Yes` the auto-complete dropdown will show right-to-left.

Comment: done that, didn't work. as i said, the combobox items are right aligned, the auto-complete isn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, I added my comboBox definition if that helps

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same and basically the only way I managed to do it is by creating my own custom control; You can simply inherit from textbox and add a listbox to it.